# bootstrap event firing only within conditional?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap event that I only want to fire if a conditional is true. It seems that .on('hidden.bs.modal',...) fires regardless of whether or not the conditional is true. Does anyone know if i'm doing something wrong or this is an issue and someone has a workaround?

```
   if($('#calcValue').val()==='SC'){
    $('#SIPAYM').val(input);
    $('#calculatorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      if($('#calcValue').val()===''){
        return;
      } else {
        openCalculator('SC2');  
      }
    })
```

I want `$('#calculatorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {}` to only fire if the `if($('#calcValue').val()==='SC')` is true, but it seems to fire everytime `#calculatorModal` is hidden.

Comment: Event handlers will fire whenever the action is taken. This is how it works. You would be best served to add that event handler once in the initial page load complete (`document.ready`) and do logic inside the event handler to see if it should call `openCalculator()`. If you want to remove an event handler based on some logic, you can use JQuery's `.off()`

Comment: Thanks. Moved it out of function it was in and to doc.ready. Adjusted logic. Working as of now. Further testing needed but at least on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#calculatorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal'...
```

This line must be executed only one time, it does not execute function body but add event handler.

You need to move your condition in the function body to make it work right.

Comment: Thanks. Moved it out of function it was in and to doc.ready. Adjusted logic. Working as of now. Further testing needed but at least on track.